# how to resolve Error :ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: oracle

I am writing query to convert string value of length 14 to date using below query

```
 select to_date(strDate,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') from TempTableExtra
```

But I am getting below error:

```
    ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

The values for column "strDate" are as like below

`20161104083815
20161104142227
20170206150945
20170206151122
20170206151130
20170306094206
20170328105454`

Comment: I suggest you look up documentation for how `TO_DATE` works. Because the data you're providing obviously doesn't match the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the format of your date variable to the mask you are using:

to_date('20161104083815', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')

Watch out that your date format start with the year - 2016, so your mask need to start with the year too -yyyy, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

This happens because you have tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

You can overcome this issue by carrying out following alteration.

```
TO_DATE('20161104083815','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

> As a general rule, if you are using the TO_DATE function, TO_TIMESTAMP
>   function, TO_CHAR function, and similar functions, make sure that the
>   literal that you provide matches the format string that you've
>   specified